# Installing in Lubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, apt, data-recovery

I don't know how to get the data recovery softwares as they're not in the Lubuntu Software Center nor Synaptic Package Manager.

1. Recuva
2. Diskdigger
3. Testdisk
4. R-Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Recuva : Recuva is not available in Lubuntu.
2. Diskdigger : Can be installed in Lubuntu. Here is [the oficial documentation for installation](http://diskdigger.org/linux).
3. `testdisk` : Available in the `universe` repository. You need to enable it first (if not done already). Run the following command to enable it (assuming you are using Lubuntu 14.04 and using official repo) :

   ```
   echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   Now run :

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Replace `trusty` with appropriate codename (you can find it with `lsb_release -c`) if you are using some other release.

   Now you can install it by :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install testdisk
   ```
4. `r-base` is also available in the `universe` repository, so you need to follow the steps mentioned above to enable it first. Then you can install it with :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install r-base
   ```

   Also `r-base-dev` if needed :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
   ```